# Sinewave.js won't play several notes when the new frequency is set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem trying to get sinewave.js-plugin to play several notes in succession.

[Link to the sinewave.js Github page](https://github.com/0xfe/experiments/tree/master/www/tone)

Here is my code.

```
scalePlayer = function(){
var command = arguments[0]; 

if (command == 'play'){
    sinewave.setFrequency(261.63); // C4
    sinewave.play();
}else if (command == 'pause'){
    sinewave.pause();
}else if (command == 'cmajor'){
    // C major scale
    var scale=[
        "130.81",
        "146.83",
        "164.81",
        "174.61",
        "196.00",
        "220.00",
        "246.94",
        "261.63"];
    s = scale.length;
    i=0;
    while (i<=s){
        setTimeout("sinewave.setFrequency("+parseFloat(scale[i])+")", 1000);
        console.log(parseFloat(scale[i]));
      i++;
     }  

}else if (command == 'test'){
        setTimeout("sinewave.setFrequency(300)", 1000);
        setTimeout("sinewave.setFrequency(500)", 1000);
}
}
```

The "test" command only plays the first note of the two, and the one that actually goes through the scale frequencies plays nothing, but prints the correct tones from the array.

What I am trying to achieve is that the "cmajor" command would play a scale, one note every 1 seconds.

I feel like the setTimeout is causing problems, and I can't understand why the "test" command won't play two different notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 while (i<s){
    setTimeout("sinewave.setFrequency("+parseFloat(scale[i])+")", 1000 * i);
    console.log(parseFloat(scale[i]));
  i++;
 }
```

Because the timeouts are all set in one after the other in the loop without delay (at cpu speed, say a few milliseconds between assignments). So you need to spread them apart as if telling the first one, "wait one second", the next one, "wait two" and so on.

While testing I also noticed `i <= s` resulted in a NaN so I changed it to `i < s`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. Feels good to hear that scale! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I was thinking what to add in the answer about your second question, but I never worked with sinewave. Is there a way you can initialize two sinewaves in the same page? (I mean, is it an object you create?) Play one note on each object.

Comment: I was wondering why the "test" bit wouldn't play two notes (one after other) when I'm setting the frequency two times. With the timeout's it should work, but when I give the argument to scalePlayer, it only plays one not (the latter, I think, with the 500 value).

Comment: I think calling `setFrequency` will just replace the previous note. Otherwise, instead of hearing a scale, we would hear something like an organ player adding notes on top of each other (we never call a function `pause`). Making two `new SineWave(context)` doesn't work?

Comment: What puzzles me is that, as you described, a setFrequency replaces the previous note, but when I assigned two different values with a one second timeout, it didn't play the first note for a second before switching to another one.

Comment: Do you mean the `command == 'test'`? `setTimeout` does not mean, run this function for one second, it means, wait one second then run the function. In `'test'`, the timeouts are set one after the other, so there should be silence for one second then whichever note happened to have setTimeout first will play.